# Doing something even if application is closed in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am developing iphone application where i want to develop feature of taking backup of files inside the application on to the server for every hour even if the application is completely closed.

I have tried to use `NSLocalNotification` but it is not calling method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

in appdelegate. The notifier showing alert box with the buttons cancel and view , If I click in view it opens the application but not calling the method. Even if user say cancel then also it should call this method.

So it is not calling web service to take backup of files. Can any one please direct me to link which does the same.

Thanking You,
Rohit Jankar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really can't do what you want. Since iOS does not allow application to run in the background unless it's is a `VOIP` client, AudioPlayer or track the user location.

The problem with the solution with `UILocalNotification` is that iOS handles the notification. When the user clicks cancel your app does not get informed about this. You can only handle the view button clicks.

The`-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` is only called if you app is run or is restored from background running.

If you app gets start by the system when you user click view on the Local notification you will need to check if there is a notification in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey]; 

if (notification) {
    //handle the notification.
}
```

Comment: Thank you rckoenes , So it is not possible to get notiftication if user clicks on cancel button. I Want to know whether the push notification will work if applicatin is totally closed does this will solve the problem of notify when app is closed.

Comment: Yes, if your app is closed and the user select `view` then your app will be started and the notification is passed in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method.

Answer (score 1):

> I am developing iphone application where i want to develop feature of
>   taking backup of files inside the application on to the server for
>   every hour even if the application is completely closed.

If you're talking about backing up files to your own server every few hours, there's really no way to do that. On the other hand, there should also be no need to do it when the app isn't running -- if the app isn't running, it can't modify data in its files and there shouldn't be any need to back up. Instead, just make sure that you back up your data periodically when the app *is* running.

If you just want to make sure that the app's data is backed up *somewhere*, consider using [iCloud](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW1). Once you've set up your app to use iCloud, your data will be backed up whenever you update it.